# SQL Server - sp_procoption marking procedure with parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Let's assume that we have simple logging procedure that run automatically during SQL Server restart:

```
USE master
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.silly_logging(id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
                               ,created_date DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
                               ,comment VARCHAR(100));
GO

-- no parametrs
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.my_procedure 
AS
INSERT INTO dbo.silly_logging(comment)
VALUES ('SQL Server Startup');
GO

-- mark procedure to start at SQL Server instance startup
EXEC sp_procoption @ProcName = 'dbo.my_procedure'
    , @OptionName = 'startup'   
    , @OptionValue = 'on';

SELECT name, is_auto_executed
FROM master.sys.procedures
WHERE is_auto_executed = 1;
-- my_procedure 1

-- restart instance
SELECT *
FROM dbo.silly_logging;
--id    created_date    comment
--1 2017-07-28 07:01:24.650 SQL Server Startup
```

If we tried the same with procedure with parameters we will get error:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.my_procedure2 @i INT = 10
AS
SELECT @i;
GO

-- mark procedure to start at SQL Server instance startup
EXEC sp_procoption @ProcName = 'dbo.my_procedure2'
    , @OptionName = 'startup'   
    , @OptionValue = 'on';
```

> Msg 15399, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_procoption,
>
> **Could not change startup option because this option is restricted to objects that have no parameters.**

But still we could `ALTER` existing procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.my_procedure @text NVARCHAR(100) = 'Default value'
AS
INSERT INTO dbo.silly_logging(comment)
VALUES (@text);
GO

-- restart instance
SELECT *
FROM dbo.silly_logging;
--id    created_date    comment
--1 2017-07-28 07:01:24.650 SQL Server Startup
--2 2017-07-28 07:03:50.510 Default value
```

Now we end up with stored procedure with parameter (default value) provided.

Drawback: It cannot be turned off .

```
EXEC sp_procoption @ProcName = 'dbo.my_procedure'
    , @OptionName = 'startup'   
    , @OptionValue = 'off';
```

> Msg 15399, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_procoption
>   Could not change startup option because this option is restricted to objects that have no parameters.

---

Of course if I use `DROP-CREATE` everything will work as expected.

- DROP PROCEDURE - object is removed, `ExecAtStartup` property is removed too
- CREATE PROCEDURE with default parameter
- EXEC sp_procoption - will return error
- procedure won't be fired

But with `CREATE-ALTER` the path is:

- CREATE PROCEDURE without parameter
- EXEC sp_procoption  (procedure will start at startup)
- ALTER PROCEDURE with default parameter
- procedure will be fired

Is there any specific reason why this work that way? Specifically, why while altering object property (like `ExecAtStartup`) is not validated?

Comment: Because the designers didn't anticipate evil people like you? What sort of answer are you looking for? Any reason why you don't simply call your procedure from a wrapper procedure that is kind enough to stick to the "no parameters" rule?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I search for some note (MSDN, BOL) about validating metadata. This is just example. Like view `WITH SCHEMABINDING` underlying objects cannot change. The question is more about internals.

Comment: To me, as a programmer, it's pretty obvious `sp_procoption` was a later addition for marking startup that does the heavy lifting of validating the procedure you're marking this way (whether to `on` or to `off`). `ALTER` is a core command of the engine, doesn't know or care about whether or not the procedure is used in startup, and will happily let you shoot yourself in the foot. This is simply emergent behavior from mechanisms operating on different levels; I'd be highly surprised if someone wrote up official documentation on this behavior. (A blog entry from a bored MVP, maybe.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Fair enough. Feel free to post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sp_procoption` explicitly checks that the procedure is valid:

- owned by dbo
- in master
- having no parameters

before it does anything.

The only effect of `sp_procoption 'proc', 'startup', 'on'`, after passing these checks, is to set the object property `ExecIsStartup` to `1` (and `off` sets it to `0`). You can verify this with `OBJECTPROPERTY`.

There is no particular reason why `ALTER PROCEDURE` couldn't check for this property and validate the procedure has no parameters and rejecting the `ALTER` otherwise, it just doesn't. As a result, you can mark a procedure for startup, alter it to have parameters, and then run into `sp_procoption` refusing to handle it anymore, even if just to turn the option off.

If this feature was implemented today, it would probably get its own syntax (`ALTER PROCEDURE Foo SET STARTUP = ON`) rather than an internal stored procedure, which Microsoft is moving away from (compare `sp_dbcmptlevel` versus `ALTER DATABASE SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL`, `sp_attach_db` versus `CREATE DATABASE FOR ATTACH`). Had it been part of `ALTER` proper, that would have also made it logical for `ALTER PROCEDURE` to have a check on parameters if the procedure was marked `STARTUP`. This is one of those things that's probably not high on anyone's priority list for feature improvements, though.

The workaround, of course, is simple enough: if you must call a procedure with (default) parameters as a startup procedure, do so from a wrapper stored procedure that really has no parameters and forwards the call. Because startup procedures can royally screw up your server if they're not carefully written, it is in fact a very good idea to use them *only* for startup (and give them names with `startup`) and not have them pull double duty in a setting with parameters where it's easy to change them inadvertently.

Answer (score 1):

The check is only in `sp_procoption`, so it will only be checked when `sp_procoption` is executed.

It still runs OK after an ALTER

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.my_procedure 
AS
RAISERROR ('fff', 10, 1) WITH LOG
GO
EXEC sp_procoption @ProcName = 'dbo.my_procedure'
    , @OptionName = 'startup'   
    , @OptionValue = 'on';
GO

-- SQL restarted. Check logs
-- Error: 50000 Severity: 10 State: 1 fff
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.my_procedure 
    @dummy int = 0
AS
RAISERROR ('ggg', 10, 1) WITH LOG
GO

-- SQL restarted. Check logs
-- Error: 50000 Severity: 10 State: 1 ggg
GO
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.my_procedure
```